# What is the optimal way to deal with nested documents with elasticsearch?

Tags: kotlin, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm trying to define the nice way of indexing a data model at Elasticsearch. I have few business entities that can contain each other, so i'm not sure should the nested or distributed structures be used.

Let me describe the example model:

```
Company {
    id: Int,
    name: String,
    address: String,
    ... 10 more unique company properties ...
}

Partner {
    id: Int
    registrationNumber: String,
    contract: String,
    ... 10 more unique partner properties ...
}

Representative {
    id: Int
    lastName: String,
    firstName: String,
    ... 10 more unique representative properties ...
}
```

For now i see tho ways of organizing index structure:

**1. Single index.** The obvious way is to create a single index `representatives`, that will contain all theis data like:

```
representatives:
    - id
    - lastName
    - firstName
    - partner:
        - id:
        - registrationNumber
        - contract
        - company:
            - id
            - name
            - address
            - other fields...
        - other fields...
    - other fields...
```

But I expect few problems here:

- If a partner contains `n` representatives then for each representative the partner and company index fields will be duplicated. Seems like this will decrease the performance.
- Saving documents with repeated info into index will cause it's size growth and that seems to be an overhead.

**2. Multi-index.** From the other side a separate index can be created for each business entity, like `companies`, `partners`, `representatives`:

```
representatives:
    - id
    - lastName
    - firstName
    - other fields...

partners:
    - id
    - registrationNumber
    - contract
    - other fields...

companies:
    - id
    - name
    - address
    - other fields...
```

This index structure will no contain duplicated data, but I expect new problems here:

- I will have to make 3 search queries instead of 1
- I wil lhave to deal somehow with multiple search query responses and make a complex logic to define the expected hits.

I don't have such an experience with Elasticsearch to understand pros & cons of these two structures...

Could anyone please give me an advice, what is better, the `1-st` or the `2-nd` option?

Answer (score 0):

The best option is usually to flatten (denormalize) your data, including the duplication that entails. This often simplifies queries and maximizes performance.

Otherwise there's other ways to model it, such as the Join type:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.3/parent-join.html#parent-join

But ensure you read up on the performance and limitations considerations:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.3/parent-join.html#_parent_join_and_performance

Some more reading (but in the fairly old/outdated "definitive guide" documentation) is here and may provide some still useful overview of the options:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/relations.html